# Code coverage report from jacoco.exec file using ant

Tags: ant, code-coverage, jacoco

I am trying to generate the Code coverage report from jacoco.exec file using ant.

My ant build is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns:jacoco="antlib:org.jacoco.ant" name="Example Ant Build with JaCoCo" default="rebuild">

  <description>
Example Ant build file that demonstrates how a JaCoCo coverage report can be itegrated into an existing build in three simple steps.
</description>

  <property name="src.dir" location="./java"/>
  <property name="result.dir" location="./target"/>
  <property name="result.classes.dir" location="./classes"/>
  <property name="result.report.dir" location="${result.dir}/site/jacoco"/>
  <property name="result.exec.file" location="./jacoco.exec"/>

  <!--  Step 1: Import JaCoCo Ant tasks  -->
  <taskdef uri="antlib:org.jacoco.ant" resource="org/jacoco/ant/antlib.xml">
    <classpath path="./jacocoant.jar"/>
  </taskdef>

  <target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${result.classes.dir}"/>
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${result.classes.dir}" debug="true" includeantruntime="false"/>
  </target>

  <target name="test" depends="compile">
    <!--
 Step 2: Wrap test execution with the JaCoCo coverage task 
-->
    <jacoco:coverage destfile="${result.exec.file}">
      <java classname="org.jacoco.examples.parser.Main" fork="true">
        <classpath path="${result.classes.dir}"/>
        <arg value="2 * 3 + 4"/>
        <arg value="2 + 3 * 4"/>
        <arg value="(2 + 3) * 4"/>
        <arg value="2 * 2 * 2 * 2"/>
        <arg value="1 + 2 + 3 + 4"/>
        <arg value="2 * 3 + 2 * 5"/>
      </java>
    </jacoco:coverage>
  </target>

  <target name="report" depends="test">
    <!--  Step 3: Create coverage report  -->
    <jacoco:report>
      <!--
 This task needs the collected execution data and ... 
-->
      <executiondata>
        <file file="${result.exec.file}"/>
      </executiondata>
      <!--  the class files and optional source files ...  -->
      <structure name="JaCoCo Ant Example">
        <classfiles>
          <fileset dir="${result.classes.dir}"/>
        </classfiles>
        <sourcefiles encoding="UTF-8">
          <fileset dir="${src.dir}"/>
        </sourcefiles>
      </structure>
      <!--  to produce reports in different formats.  -->
      <html destdir="${result.report.dir}"/>
      <csv destfile="${result.report.dir}/report.csv"/>
      <xml destfile="${result.report.dir}/report.xml"/>
    </jacoco:report>
  </target>

  <target name="rebuild" depends="compile,test,report"/>

</project>
```

But while compiling the ant build I get the errors related to undefined symbols in the code. How do I remove them?

An example of the error is:

```
compile:
[javac] Compiling 13 source files to C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\jacoco\classes
[javac] C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\jacoco\java\file.java:13: error: package org.abc.def.ghi.primitives does not exist
[javac] import org.abc.def.ghi.primitives.Request;
```

These imports are from my code and internally defined but does ant doesn't recognize them. I have already copied all the .java and .class files.

Any pointers will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is **not** a code coverage problem. Your code is failing at the *compile* step. It's the *javac* command throwing the error.You need to solve this problem first.

I don't understand what you mean by:

> .... I have already copied all the .java and .class files.